# Failed to write core dump when trying to execute .jar file

Tags: java, windows

I've been trying to google this error for a couple of days but i have not found a solution.

This error happens when i try to start a java program that i use to administrate my server for the game Chivalry: Medieval Warfare.

When i try to start the program a black "cmd" window just blinks for a fraction of a second, to be clear, this happens before the program starts.

Here's what i use to try to start the program: java -jar ChivAdmin.jar

this is what the cmd type window is showing me:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffde121fd0c, pid=2880, tid=0x0000000000002788
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>   Problematic frame:
>   C  [d3d9.dll+0xfd0c]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>     http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>   The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>   See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

And here is the full error dump: https://pastebin.com/HMRzA4ZQ
`code.here(to_make_my_link_work)`

what i've tried so far is uninstalling java completely and reinstalling newest version of both 32bit and 64bit, also tried with each of 32bit and 64bit on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the Graphivs driver. Issue is already discussed and there is solution proposed, [here](https://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5058) 
Kindly follow to avoid this crash